# Keras backend.repeat_elements not working?

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I'm trying to create a simple matrix here, repeated for each sample in my batch.

Here is the matrix:

```
balanceMatrix = np.array([[[5,10,10],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]])
print(balanceMatrix.shape)

balanceMatrix = K.constant(balanceMatrix)
print(K.shape(balanceMatrix).eval())
```

So far, so good, I have the expected matrix shaped (1,3,3). 
Now I want it to be repeated for every sample in the batch (say 60000 samples). From keras [documentation](https://keras.io/backend/), all I should do is this:

```
balanceMatrix = K.repeat_elements(balanceMatrix, 60000,axis=0)
print(K.shape(balanceMatrix).eval())
```

But this raises the following error, which I can't simply understand:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-4356baf13de8> in <module>()
     20 balanceMatrix = K.constant(balanceMatrix)
     21 print(K.shape(balanceMatrix).eval())
---> 22 balanceMatrix = K.repeat_elements(balanceMatrix, 60000,axis=0)
     23 print(K.shape(balanceMatrix).eval())
     24 

c:\users\ut65\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py in repeat_elements(x, rep, axis)
    743     if hasattr(x, '_keras_shape'):
    744         y._keras_shape = list(x._keras_shape)
--> 745         repeat_dim = x._keras_shape[axis]
    746         if repeat_dim is not None:
    747                 y._keras_shape[axis] = repeat_dim * rep

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What is going on??
I know, I can do that with `np.repeat(balanceMatrix,60000,axis=0)` first and then creating the keras tensor, but shouldn't the keras option work as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `K.variable` would help here:

```
balanceMatrix = K.variable(value=balanceMatrix)
```

Comment: Thanks :) -- Do you know why? --- After testing, the numpy option is way faster...

Comment: @Daniel sorry I was traveling and couldn't write a lot in my mobile :/ I don't know the exact reason but I had an identical problem in the past. My guess would be that Keras is trying to repeat the structure *inplace* and using a constant makes it crash (not sure tho). And yes, for these operations that repeat structures numpy will be almost always faster. However, repeating in numpy and then moving everything to Keras should have similar performance that moving to Keras and then repeating in there (for a sufficiently large repeats).